# Is it possible to use tag function arguments to produce the exact same sequence of literals and placeholders?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

The book https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html has this example in it:

```
var say = "a bird in hand > two in the bush";
var html = htmlEscape `<div> I would just like to say : ${say}</div>`;

// a sample tag function
function htmlEscape(literals, ...placeholders) {
    let result = "";
    ...
   // interleave the literals with the placeholders
   for (let i = 0; i < placeholders.length; i++) {
     result += literals[i];
     result += placeholders[i]
```

Is it possible to produce the exact same input string escaped in this case?  For example what would happen if the placeholder came first?

### Clarification

The author of html escape function assumes that the first literal should be first in the string returned by the html escape function.  But what if the placeholder `${say}` came first?  So in other words do tag functions have any way to assess what the sequence of placeholders and literals are?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact same input string"? What does your expected result look like?

Comment: Are you looking for [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)?

Comment: The author of the example start the string returned by the html escape function by first adding the first string literal, then escaping the the placeholder value, then adding the next string literal and so forth.  However how would one detect whether the strings starts with a literal or a placeholder?

Comment: A template literal always starts and ends with a character component, which alternate with substitutions. It always has one more string than substitutions. A placeholder can never come "first" - it might come after an empty string, though.

Comment: Notice that a tag function can never produce placeholders, it does not know about them. It only gets passed the placement values.

Comment: @deceze is there anything else about the question that is unclear?

Comment: @bergi got it - Thanks.  Hopefully that can be official answer whenever @ deceze decides to remove the hold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141459/discussion-between-ole-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template literal always starts and ends with a character component, which alternate with substitutions. It always has one more string part than substitutions. A placeholder can never come "first" - it might come after an empty string, though:

```
const say = 42;
tag `{say} it is`;
function tag(strings, ...placements) {
    console.assert(strings[0] === "")
    console.assert(strings[1] === " it is");
    console.assert(placments[0] === 42);
    console.assert(strings.length == placements.length+1);
}
```

Notice that a tag function can never produce placeholders (names), it does not know about them. It only gets passed the placement values.